# How Hbase split the records in multiple regionServer?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

I have cluster setup of `Hbase`:

`1` HMaster Node and 3 Region Servers

I would like to know that:  When we insert the multiple rows in table, than how Hbase split the records across multiple regionServer ?

Does `Hfile` has sorted key value records(`rowKey:cf:TimeStamp`) ?

If yes than How Hbase maintain the sorted key order in Transaction Table.

I read that META table mentain the table information like (Table_name, Region(StartKey-EndKey)) is it correct ?

Comment: I got your point upto some extend. If you can give me some idea on this example than it would be great. i.e I have table T1 which has rowKey as studentID(Integer). I have 1 Master and 3 Region server(R1,R2,R3). Lets assume that I split the record as 300 row. Now multiple people entering the records in T1 with key between [1-1000]. So now who is mainting the sorted order of Key in Hfile ? I read that META table has info like [T1,R1[1-300], [T1,R2[301-600], is it correct ? if yes than who take care for this entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your questions, but when you insert multiple rows into tables, lookups are made to the `.META.` table to find which region should get the mutations and the client then sends it to the corresponding hbase regionserver.

HFiles are indeed sorted files with keyvalues, which look more like

> `<keylength> <valuelength> <rowlength> <row> <columnfamilylength> <columnfamily> <columnqualifier> <timestamp> <keytype> <value>`

http://hbase.apache.org/book/hfilev2.html

http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.html

Sorting occurs in all compactions i.e. when you add a row it is added to the `memtable`, which once filled with enough rows in the `memtable` it will sort them and dump them to a `HFile`(i.e Merge compaction).  When multiple HFiles exist for a `region` HBase will merge them all together in a sorted fashion (called Major Compaction).

The META Table maintains Region information, such as table name, region start key, end key, and which server is serving it.

Comment: I got your point upto some extend. If you can give me some idea on this example than it would be great. i.e I have table T1 which has rowKey as studentID(Integer). I have 1 Master and 3 Region server(R1,R2,R3). Lets assume that I split the record as 300 row. Now multiple people entering the records in T1 with key between [1-1000]. So now who is mainting the sorted order of Key in Hfile ? I read that META table has info like [T1,R1[1-300], [T1,R2[301-600], is it correct ? if yes than who take care for this entry ?

Comment: If you are meaning that what if you do a batch put of rows across multiple regions, the client will contact the regionserver with the .META. table for where to send each row (regionserver) and then send them to their respective destination.  The META table indeed has that information. So if you send a user with ID(250) and ID(350) in the same operation, they will go to the correct regionserver which will keep them sorted.

Comment: I read that Hbase use LSM(Log Structured Merge) Tree for merging the in-memory tree with disk tree. On that case, Client Put the data on R1 & region for that data is R2 than on that case In-Memory data of R1 Merge with R2's Disk Data ? Is it correct ?

Comment: No, a client should never send data to a regionserver that does not contain the region the data should go to. I'm not sure exactly what would happen if this were the case, perhaps sent to the master to then be resent to the proper regionserver.  In any case most of this information can be found here: http://hbase.apache.org/book.html

Comment: I gone through below link which describe about read/write flow. 
http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/06/hbase-write-path/
I don't get one part :When data comes from client, it store in-memory in MemStore and than sort and dump into Hfile (Merge Compaction). So on that case When LSM comes into picture ?